# Word request for the main urban cleaning organization

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I was wondering what do you call the organization that deals with cleaning and beautifying a city / town organizing street sweepers, big garbage cans in each urban district etc. in the United States?
I used to think that it was called "[municipality](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/municipality)", but so accidentally I was looking that up in a dictionary when I found out that it is absolutely a different meaning comparing the concept I used to think it means.

Comment: It depends on a range of things and is different in different areas of the same country let alone the differences between countries. As asked your question cannot be answered in a useful way.

Comment: One option for some places might make use of the concept “sanitation” as part of the title.

Comment: As is often the case, there may be no equivalent. What is the organization called in your country? In the U.S. a large municipality (city, town, village, etc.) might operate its own waste disposal service, a smaller one will contract with a private company. In some states, this is a county responsibility. In some places, there is no such service. The organization which handles household waste removal will most likely not be the same one that handles street sweeping or urban beautification.

Comment: "Extra" neighborhood upkeep beyond what the government provides may be taken up by a wide variety of private organizations including business improvement districts, homeowners associations, or community leagues.

Comment: Well, @choster in my country there is a government organization which provides sanitation services throughout urban areas allover the country. Of course there are some authorized, private organizations that are dealing with some parts of this great everyday task. Then I was wondering what would you call such an organization to make a good sense in English? Does "sanitation org." work?

Comment: As we are pointing out there is no term that will be widely understood to mean what you want to say. You will need to write out what you are referring to in as many words as that takes.

Comment: Maybe also clarify whether you want the official word used by the organisation itself or the word used by the general public to refer to it. In my experience in the UK these are not in general the same.

Comment: Websites of borough and city councils in England don't generally refer to a department, but talk about a service such as "Waste and recycling" or "Bins, recyling and waste".

Comment: Does "urban waste and recycling system" work @Colin Fine? Or even "urban waste and sanitation system"

Comment: @A-friend: Not in  the UK (I don't know about anywhere else). _System_ suggests some physical piece of engineering: pipes and tanks, or maybe electronics. Nothing to do with people or vehicles going round collecting something

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is a single universal term. Random DuckDuckGoing produced links to:

- [The City of New York, Department of Sanitation](https://www1.nyc.gov/assets/dsny/site/home).
- [LA Sanitation and Environment](https://www.lacitysan.org/san/faces/home)
- [Chicago Department of Streets and Sanitation](https://www.chicago.gov/city/en/depts/streets.html).

I used both "sanitation" and "garbage" as buzzwords. Looks like "sanitation" is the preferred term. Understandably so because it sure sounds more high-browed than "garbage collection".

Comment: Sanitation is a word barely used outside North America.

Comment: @jwpfox Then may be you should post another answer :-)

Comment: What do you think of "the waste and sanitation department" @Jyrku Lahtonen? Can it imply the measage in my question for most native speakers?

Comment: @A-friend jwpfox is a native speaker, I'm not. If they say "sanitation" is somewhat restricted to North America, there is little reason to doubt that. Also, it is easy to imagine that elsewhere a term other than "department" is more common to refer to a division of municipally run services.